# Cannot create new database table in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

[image: there's no create table option when right clicked]

I'm trying to make a new project using Visual Basic on Visual Studio with database in it. I click on the solution, add new item and select the server based database, but when I double click the database and right click on the table, it didn't show any option to create a new table. why is it? All the videos I saw on Youtube has that create table option

Comment: Can you show the ConnectionString?

Comment: I don't have any, all the videos i saw immediately create table like that, without any code beforehand